# How can I test a Crosswalk application with BrowserStack?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, appium, crosswalk, browserstack

At our company, we maintain a legacy Android application which uses [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) to embed a web view. We would like to implement automated end-to-end tests for this app using Appium and ChromeDriver.

Unfortunately, the version of Chrome used by Crosswalk is modified in such a way that ChromeDriver cannot connect to it. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4597#issuecomment-402785867), and the recommended workaround is to use a custom patched version of ChromeDriver instead.

This solution works for running tests locally. But BrowserStack doesn't seem to allow for supplying a custom build of ChromeDriver. I can [choose from a set list of versions](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities#chrome-capabilities), but that won't help, as none of those versions have the Crosswalk patch.

Is there a way to make this work with BrowserStack?

Answer (score 0):

I had used BrowserStack for my native app tests as well. Currently, they do not provide any custom capability to select the ChromeDriver version.